# Unresponsive navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out a simple `bootstrap navbar`. However, my `data-toggle` isn't working.

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div> 
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Meet the Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: what's the relation php? there's no code to support the question or relevant information.

Comment: The PHP tag was a typo.

Comment: are all required css/js/jquery libraries loaded? look at your developer console.

Comment: btw, that dot in here `data-target=".navbar-collapse"` is the/a problem, remove it. Dots only belong in the css class, i.e.: `.class{...}` not in data models.

Comment: Yes I triple-checked. They're loaded.

Comment: The tge dot in data-target=".navbar-collapse" is a class selector to display collapse the <ul> when the button is clicked. I tried removing the dot but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-collapse"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li><a href="#">Meet the Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meet the Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The problem was the `data-target=".navbar-collapse"`.

Dots only belong to classes. You have to use # and an id for the collapsible part `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">`

The bootstrap doc is pretty good. You will find it **[here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)**